# Not all class methods listed in the scala online language reference?

Tags: scala

I am looking at scala.io.Source.  It has a bunch of

```
   fromXXXX()
```

methods.  However in the [online reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.io.Source) I do not see them.

Where are those methods - and more generally a comprehensive list of all methods on scala.io.Source - located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing the documentation of the class source. Please see the documentation of [object source](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.io.Source$) which link(http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.io.Source$ , inline url is ignoring the $) to which is listed on the right side of the page.

Comment: Ah I see. after clicking the link we manually add the $ and that goes to the object.

Comment: There is link the right which say object source.( toggle between object and class source it seems).

Comment: Did not see that before. it is not obvious.

Comment: Yes, not obvious. Me too discovered it pretty recently.